# Xamarin DesignTime Custom Controls Render in XCode, edit control properties in DesignTime

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am developing an application on Xamarin.iOS and MvvmCross platforms. I use `xib` files instead of storyboards for design interfaces (navigation in my app based on ViewModels). How can I use Xcode's Interface Builder to render my custom controls & edit properties in `IB`?

Adding attributes `[DesignTimeVisible (true)]` for class and `[Export ("Counter"), Browsable (true)]` for properties does not work for XCode Interface Builder.

As far as I know in Objective-C classes there must be set `@IBDesignable` & `@IBInspectable`, if you want design time support in Xcode for custom controls.

Comment: have you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Comment: @BradAllred That is indeed the documentation for the requested feature in Xcode, but Xamarin.iOS/Monotouch does not implement that, afaik, hence the bounty.

Comment: So, what happens is you edit your code and the changes are shown in interface builder?

Comment: This reads like a feature request to the Xamarin project. Either that or subclass their stuff to make it follow the IB requirements for previewing custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible with XCode Interface Builder since it needs to build the custom control in order to present it. And the XCode project generated by Xamarin is not buildable it is used only to track changes and generate C# code.

However you can take a look at the [Xamarin Studio’s iOS designer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/). I think it has the feature you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but Xamarin do support basically the same thing, only using their iOS designer (which I have found rather flaky...)

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/

edit: I just noticed the guy above also gave the same solution, his link is to the designer docs, mine is to the custom properties walkthrough so i'll leave it up :)